# How to visualize correlation of discrete data using scatter_matrix in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation, discrete-mathematics

```
for attribute in ['alcohol','chlorides','density']:
    compare = wine_data[["quality", attribute]]
    plot = pp.scatter_matrix(compare)
    plt.show()
```

I found the following graph. Quality is an integer in the range of 0-10. ['alcohol','chlorides','density'] are continues data. The correlations between ['alcohol','chlorides','density'] and quality are 0.432733,-0.305599 and -0.207202, respectively. How do I understand the three graphs below? Is there a better way to visualize the correlation of discrete datas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems far more like a statistics question than a programming one. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer Seaborn's regplot function - which will graph the same scatterplot you see here along with a regression line on top o fit. The regression line will help you understand whether the correlation is positive or negative (upward / downward sloping) as well as providing error bars in shading around the regression line.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html